# Loading Device Specific UI using InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

When writing device specific XAML using UWP, we can create different XAML views for each device family. For example, `Track.DeviceFamily-Xbox.xaml`. This page uses the same back-end as `Track.xaml` but will load when using the app on Xbox.

We can also pass in a URL to the `InitializeComponent()` method to load a specific xaml page.

Now I'm wondering if I can combine these methods together. In this example, I would like the load the Xbox UI when fullscreen. The following code would be the ideal way of doing it, but.. well I'm here, so it does not work :)

```
 public Track()
 {
        // If the app is full screen, we can use the Xbox UI
        if (App.IsFullScreen)
        {
            InitializeComponent(new Uri("ms-appx:///Views/Track.DeviceFamily-Xbox.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // etc ...    
    }
```

Has anyone got any ideas with what I can do? Is there a way to load the Xbox specific view, or should I just create XAML view, call it `TrackXbox.xaml`, and then handle loading that view when the user is full screen or running on the Xbox?

Answer (score 1):

Okay So what you're trying to do might not be possible but what's the way to implement this kind of functionality is:

1. For Device specific views, use multiple folders of device family and add a XAML view in it. The compiler automatically loads the xaml from the folder and the codebehind from the normal view. More information about this [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b876a/set-specific-device-family-xaml-views-in-windows-10-uwp/).

But what you want is to switch between multiple views on app resize so what you can do is use `VisualStates` something like below:

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="900"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <--For larger screensizes-->
                    <Setter Value="3" Target="MyDummyButton.(Grid.RowSpan)"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Mobile">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>

                    <Setter Value="1" Target="MyDummyButton.(Grid.RowSpan)"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

and now when you want to switch between multiple views in the same device family, what you can do is from c# in codeBehind

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions);
```

more information about switching visual states [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, have been quite busy. I am unable to easily apply the Visual State method due to the XAML being very different for Xbox and PC. But thanks for the help!